# Increasing trainig losses in Neural network

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

I trying implement neural network from scratch .But the thing is loss increases while training the. The Neural network consist of three layer(input,hindden,output). I have added regualrisation in loss function Compute_loss.
Here is the code.

```
import numpy as np
import random
# define neural network class
class Neuralnetwork():
    def __init__(self, X, Y,regulization_L2=False,regulization_L1=False,dropout_forward_bool=False): # initialize parameters
        
        self.size=[32*32, 100, 10]  # size of input, hidden and output layer
        self.parameters = {}   # initialize parameters
        self.learning_rate = 0.0001  # learning rate
        self.num_iterations = 100
        self.X = None
        self.Y = None
        self.loss = []
        self.regulization_l2=regulization_L2  
        self.regulization_l1=regulization_L1
        self.lambda_=0.000001
        self.dropout=0.02
        self.dropout_forword_bool=dropout_forward_bool
        

    def initialize_parameters(self):  # initialize parameters for neural network 
        np.random.seed(2)
        self.input_layer_size = self.size[0]   # size of input layer
        self.hidden_layer_size = self.size[1]  # size of hidden layer
        self.output_layer_size = self.size[2]   # size of output layer
        self.parameters['W1'] = np.random.randn(self.hidden_layer_size, self.input_layer_size) * 0.01 # initialize weights for hidden layer
        self.parameters['b1'] = np.zeros((self.hidden_layer_size, 1))   # initialize bias for hidden layer
        self.parameters['W2'] = np.random.randn(self.output_layer_size, self.hidden_layer_size) * 0.01 # initialize weights for output layer
        self.parameters['b2'] = np.zeros((self.output_layer_size, 1))  # initialize bias for output layer
        

    
    def sigmoid(self, Z): # sigmoid function
        return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-Z))
    
    def relu(self, Z):  # relu function
        return np.maximum(0, Z)
    
    def sigmoid_backward(self, dA, Z):  # derivative of sigmoid function
        sig = self.sigmoid(Z)
        return dA * sig * (1 - sig)
    
    def relu_backward(self, dA, Z):  # derivative of relu function
        dZ = np.array(dA, copy=True)
        dZ[Z <= 0] = 0
        return dZ
    
    def forward_propagation(self, X,):  # forward propagation function for neural network 

        # dropout the nodes by making the weights zero and bias zero for the nodes
        
        if self.dropout_forword_bool==True and self.dropout>0:
            for node in range(self.parameters['W1'].shape[0]):
                for weight in range(self.parameters['W1'].shape[1]):
                    if random.uniform(0,1) < self.dropout:
                        self.parameters['W1'][node][weight] = 0
                
                        self.parameters['b1'][node]=0

        # calculate Z1, A1, Z2, A2
        Z1 = np.dot(self.parameters['W1'], X.T) + self.parameters['b1'] # calculate Z1
        A1 = self.relu(Z1)
        Z2 = np.dot(self.parameters['W2'], A1) + self.parameters['b2']
        A2 = self.sigmoid(Z2)
        return A2, Z2, A1, Z1


    def L1_regularization(self, weights): # L1 regularization function to avoid overfitting 
        
        sum=0
        # calculate sum of absolute values of weights

        for i in range(weights.shape[0]):
            for j in range(weights.shape[1]):
                sum=sum+abs(weights[i][j])

        ans=self.lambda_ *sum # multiply sum with lambda value to set the regularization strength
        return ans

    def L2_regularization(self, weights): 
        sum=0
        # calculate sum of square of weights 
        for i in range(weights.shape[0]):
            for j in range(weights.shape[1]):
                sum=sum+((weights[i][j])**2)

        ans=self.lambda_ *sum
        return ans


    def compute_cost(self, A2, Y): # compute cost function
        m = len(Y)
        if self.regulization_l2==True:     # if L2 regularization is true
        
            cost = -1/m * np.sum(np.multiply(Y, np.log(A2)) + np.multiply((1 - Y), np.log(1 - A2)))  # using cross entropy loss function Formula 
            cost = np.squeeze(cost) # squeeze the cost value to remove the extra dimension
            #cost=cost + (self.L2_regularization(self.parameters['W1']) + self.L2_regularization(self.parameters['W2']))/m # add L2 regularization cost to the loss function
            return cost
        elif self.regulization_l1==True:  # if L1 regularization is true
            cost = -1/m * np.sum(np.multiply(Y, np.log(A2)) + np.multiply((1 - Y), np.log(1 - A2))) # using cross entropy loss function Formula
            cost = np.squeeze(cost)
            #cost=cost + (self.L1_regularization(self.parameters['W1']) + self.L1_regularization(self.parameters['W2']))/m # add L1 regularization cost to the loss function
            return cost
        
        else:
            cost = -1/m * np.sum(np.multiply(Y, np.log(A2)) + np.multiply((1 - Y), np.log(1 - A2))) # using cross entropy loss function Formula Without regularization
            cost = np.squeeze(cost)
            return cost
    



  
    
    def backward_propagation(self, X, Y, A2, Z2, A1, Z1):
        
        # backward propagation function for neural network does the backpropagation and calculates the gradients of weights and bias
        

        m = len(Y)
        dZ2 = A2 - Y.T  # dz2 is the derivative of cost function with respect to z2


        if self.regulization_l1==True:
            # calculate dW2 and add L1 regularization to it
            dW2 = np.dot(dZ2, A1.T) / m + self.L1_regularization(self.parameters['W2'])/m  # calculate dW2 and add L1 regularization to it 
            db2 = np.sum(dZ2, axis=1, keepdims=True) / m

            dA= np.dot(self.parameters['W2'].T, dZ2) 
            dZ1 = dA * self.relu_backward(dA, Z1)  
            dW1 = np.dot(dZ1, X) / m + self.L1_regularization(self.parameters['W1'])/m
            db1 = np.sum(dZ1, axis=1, keepdims=True) / m
            return dW1, dW2, db1, db2
        elif self.regulization_l2==True:
            # calculate dW2 and add L2 regularization to it
            dW2 = np.dot(dZ2, A1.T) / m + self.L2_regularization(self.parameters['W2'])/m
            db2 = np.sum(dZ2, axis=1, keepdims=True) / m

            dA= np.dot(self.parameters['W2'].T, dZ2)
            dZ1 = dA * self.relu_backward(dA, Z1)
            dW1 = np.dot(dZ1, X) / m + self.L2_regularization(self.parameters['W1'])/m
            db1 = np.sum(dZ1, axis=1, keepdims=True) / m
            return dW1, dW2, db1, db2
        else:   
            # calculate dW2 and db2 without regularization 
            dW2 = np.dot(dZ2, A1.T) / m
            db2 = np.sum(dZ2, axis=1, keepdims=True) / m

            dA= np.dot(self.parameters['W2'].T, dZ2)
            dZ1 = dA * self.relu_backward(dA, Z1)
            dW1 = np.dot(dZ1, X) / m
            db1 = np.sum(dZ1, axis=1, keepdims=True) / m
            return dW1, dW2, db1, db2

        



            
    def update_parameters(self, dW1, dW2, db1, db2):
        # update the parameters using the gradients calculated in backward propagation

        self.parameters['W1'] = self.parameters['W1'] - self.learning_rate * dW1
        self.parameters['W2'] = self.parameters['W2'] - self.learning_rate * dW2
        self.parameters['b1'] = self.parameters['b1'] - self.learning_rate * db1
        self.parameters['b2'] = self.parameters['b2'] - self.learning_rate * db2

    
    def fit(self, X, Y):
        # fit function is used to train the model
    
        self.initialize_parameters() # initialize the parameters
        for i in range(self.num_iterations): # loop over the number of iterations
            A2, Z2, A1, Z1 = self.forward_propagation(X)  # forward propagation
            cost = self.compute_cost(A2, Y)
            dW1, dW2, db1, db2 = self.backward_propagation(X, Y, A2, Z2, A1, Z1) # backward propagation to calculate the gradients
            # save the gradients in the parameters dictionary
            self.parameters['dW1'] = dW1
            self.parameters['dW2'] = dW2
            self.parameters['db1'] = db1
            self.parameters['db2'] = db2
            
            # update the parameters
            self.update_parameters(dW1, dW2, db1, db2)
            self.loss.append(cost)

            if i % 10 == 0:
        
                print(f'Cost after iteration {i}: {cost}')

    def predict(self, X):
        # predict function is used to predict the output for the given input
        A2, _, _, _ = self.forward_propagation(X)  # forward propagation
        predictions = np.round(A2)  # round the output to get the predictions
        return predictions
    
    def plot_loss(self): # plot the loss
        plt.plot(self.loss)
        plt.xlabel('Iterations')
        plt.ylabel('Loss')
        plt.show()
    
    def accuracy(self, X, Y):
        predictions = self.predict(X)
        return (np.sum((predictions == Y) / Y.shape[1])) * 100

    def check_gradient(self, X, Y):  # check the gradient
        # calculate the gradient using backpropagation
        A2, Z2, A1, Z1 = self.forward_propagation(X)
        epsilon = 1e-7
        dW1, dW2, db1, db2 = self.backward_propagation(X, Y, A2, Z2, A1, Z1)  # backward propagation to calculate the gradients
        for i in range(1, 3):
            # calculate the gradient using the formula
            self.parameters[f'W{i}'] += epsilon  # add epsilon to W1
            A2, Z2, A1, Z1 = self.forward_propagation(X)  # forward propagation
            cost_plus = self.compute_cost(A2, Y)
            self.parameters[f'W{i}'] -= 2 * epsilon # subtract epsilon from W1
            A2, Z2, A1, Z1 = self.forward_propagation(X)  # forward propagation
            cost_minus = self.compute_cost(A2, Y)  
            gradient = (cost_plus - cost_minus) / (2 * epsilon)  # calculate the gradient using the formula
            
            numerator = np.linalg.norm(gradient - self.parameters[f'dW{i}']) # calculate the numerator using the norm  of the difference between the gradients
            denominator = np.linalg.norm(gradient) + np.linalg.norm(self.parameters[f'dW{i}']) # calculate the denominator using the norm of the gradients
            difference = numerator / denominator  
            if(difference > 1e-7):
                print("There is a mistake in the backward propagation! difference = " + str(difference))
```

when i call mdoel:

```
print('--------------- model with L2 Regularization --------------------')
model_L2 = Neuralnetwork(x_train, y_train,regulization_L2=True, regulization_L1=False,dropout_forward_bool=False)
model_L2.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

here is the output

```
--------------- model with L2 Regularization --------------------
Cost after iteration 0: 1430.3418627178976
Cost after iteration 10: 1446.5808681718697
Cost after iteration 20: 1459.8884483327824
```

How do i correct this and why is it increasing?

Answer (score 0):

Your example is missing x_train so I couldn't reproduce your behavior - but it's not a tragedy because I made something that might help you - a small notebook in which I implemented the backprop. alg. as an example to understand it myself. I have made 5 versions in which I go step by step from a simple numpy implentation to one with pytorch and cuda. For your problem the versions 1 to 3 of the implementation are interesting. I hope this helps you.

[backpropagationnotebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/frankausberlin/notebook-collection/blob/main/backpropagationnotebook.ipynb)